# Debian "Stretch" freezes frequently, particularly when using certain browsers

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, debian, freeze

I recently installed Debian Stretch, and if not for this issue, I'd be quite happy with it.

```
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
```

The problem is that the system keeps locking up and becoming completely unresponsive. I can't even switch out of the GUI to at least shutdown normally. This problem seems to be particularly acute when either Firefox or Chrome is running (it's rare to get more than an hour uninterrupted).  Vivaldi, by contrast, provides a much more stable experience (it can go for days without incident). I am not sure what is driving this, but here are a couple odd aspects of the last freeze.

**SYSLOG**

The last failure occurred at 12:51:35.  When I checked syslog, I got an unrelated error (related to an ntopng script failure) at 12:51:18.  (I believe it is unrelated because this issue arises whether or not ntopng is running.) The next entry looks like a dump:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

...and so on and so forth.  At this point,the system locked up.

**KERN.LOG**

By contrast, the last thing in the kernel log is a string of thermal events:

```
proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
```

However, the last one was well before the event occurred (12:44:26).  I am not sure if this is a red herring.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?  The other posts on similar issues seem to be largely caught up in a graphics controller issue, but I feel like that would be weird here given the integrated nature of my controller. That said, I can definitely be missing something.

Comment: Wild guess: It's overheating, and somehow CPU throttling does not work? Can you install `lm-sensors`, and have a look at the temperatures?

Comment: Afraid there is no intel on this front. If temps are spiking, the freeze happens before lm-sensor can register it.  The temp tends to be around 62 C when it freezes, but before the freeze I see temperatures that are notably higher (circa 68).

Comment: If it's only 68C shortly before it freezes, I don't think it's overheating - it needs to be much hotter before it becomes a problem. Rising temperature just means higher load on the CPU(s), but that by itself doesn't help in narrowing down the problem. Next thing I'd try is to find out if it's graphics related, or just connected to higher load - ssh in and make it do some work (compile the kernel etc.), or disable drm and switch the X driver, or ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes during December, I started experiencing the same issue (on an i7-5557U with Iris Graphics 6100). I've tried reverting to a slightly older kernel (4.9.0-3-amd64) but this did not change anything. It crashes every few minutes (so debugging the issue is quite tough, it sometimes even crashes before I can log in). I will now try to ssh to it, in order to know if "only" X is crashing or the whole computer. My guess is that everything is locked, since I can not see anything in the logs. If I run in console only, then everything works fine...

Comment: I've tried booting on a USB stick with Debian Stretch Live, and everything is fine, no more freezes (although the kernel is 4.9.0-4 like on my normal system). So there is nothing wrong with the  kernel...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you mean you just booted once from a live USB, and then all issues were resolved for normal boots after that?

Comment: The problem has been identified, there is a Debian bug report open: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=884116 . To make it short: either downgrade your kernel or use a backport from testing.

Comment: This looks like a discussion of your own, different, problem.  It doesn't appear to be a solution to the problem in this question, or even relate to it.